# How should I get variable in label in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift, so I made a new iOS project. I have declared a variable and placed a content into it. Also I have created `IBOutlet` for label and I tried to get a variable in my label. Swift compiler said: `'UInt32' is not convertible to 'String'`.

What's wrong with my code?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var Mark : UILabel

    @IBAction func Rate(sender : UIButton) {
        var chibotar = arc4random_uniform(6)
        Mark.text = chibotar // error on this line
    }
```

Comment: You need to be explicit about converting between types. Try `Mark.text = String(chibotar)`. The compiler is pretty clear here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert it to a String. You have several ways to do it in this case:

```
let chibotar = arc4random_uniform(6) // let instead of var for constants
Mark.text = String(chibotar)
Mark.text = chibotar.description
Mark.text = "\(chibotar)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the following line

Label will display String Values so convert to Sting using following Line.

```
 var chibotar = arc4random_uniform(6)
 Mark.text = "\(chibota)"
 //(or)
 Mark.text = String(chibotar)
```

It will work